# Do both the sentences mean the same thing?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-choice

> 1. Your judgement is as clouded as John's was when he did that stupid thing.
> 2. Your judgement is as clouded as how clouded John's judgement was when he did that stupid thing.

- Do both these sentences mean the same thing?
- Are they grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you can omit the "how clouded" in the second sentence as it's repetitive and unnecessary. When reading the first sentence I completely understand the meaning just as much as the second sentence. Therefore the extra "how clouded" is unnecessary and can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences mean the same thing, however, your expansion of the original simile in your example

> Your judgement is as clouded as how clouded John's judgement was when he did that stupid thing.

is understandable but awkward and verbose.

In school, it is taught that

> Your judgement is as clouded as John's

can be expanded (for meaning) to

> Your judgement is as clouded as John's *judgement is clouded*

Your second sentence could be reformulated as

> Your judgement is as clouded as John's judgement was clouded when he did that stupid thing.
>   Your judgement is as clouded as John's when he did that stupid thing.

In the second sentence (above) "was" is redundant since past tense is implied by "did".